# C heapsort crashes whenever run, windows reports error

Tags: c, windows, sorting, crash, heapsort

I am currently having some trouble with this heapsort, I have no errors on compilation, however, when I run the program, it crashes, as in windows says it crashes, there is no output in the terminal, only the report from windows.  Here is the code.  The file is a simple line by line file with numbers in it, it has 10,000 elements in it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void heapsort(int[],int);
void heapify(int[],int);
void adjust(int[],int);
int main() {
    int n,i,a[10000];
    // printf("\nEnter the limit:");
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int j=0;
    int num;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) {
        a[j] = num;
        j++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    // scanf("%d",&n);
    // printf("\nEnter the elements:");
    // for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    //   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    heapsort(a,n);
    printf("\nThe Sorted Elements Are:\n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      printf("\t%d",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
void heapsort(int a[],int n) {
    int i,t;
    heapify(a,n);
    for (i=n-1;i>0;i--) {
        t = a[0];
        a[0] = a[i];
        a[i] = t;
        adjust(a,i);
    }
}
void heapify(int a[],int n) {
    int k,i,j,item;
    for (k=1;k<n;k++) {
        item = a[k];
        i = k;
        j = (i-1)/2;
        while((i>0)&&(item>a[j])) {
            a[i] = a[j];
            i = j;
            j = (i-1)/2;
        }
        a[i] = item;
    }
}
void adjust(int a[],int n) {
    int i,j,item;
    j = 0;
    item = a[j];
    i = 2*j+1;
    while(i<=n-1) {
        if(i+1 <= n-1)
           if(a[i] <a[i+1])
            i++;
        if(item<a[i]) {
            a[j] = a[i];
            j = i;
            i = 2*j+1;
        } else
           break;
    }
    a[j] = item;
}
```

Comment: `heapsort(a,n);` uses *uninitialised variable* `n`. Perhaps you should be using `j`.

Comment: its initilized at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: Nope, it is defined but not initialised.

Comment: oh, your right, I feel silly

Comment: thanks, that fixed it, cant believe it was such a tiny issue, lol

Comment: if you make a regular answer, Ill vote it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Local (automatic) variables are not initialised. You are passing `n` to your function `heapsort` which was defined but not initialised. I see that the commented out code would have worked, since `n` was an input value. Better change the `j` to `n` to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n,i,a[10000]; // doesn't initialize n, This is just a declaration
```

Standard ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.7.9->10 states

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Then you're

```
heapsort(a,n); // calling heapsort with arbitrary n
```

You might consider changing

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0
```

to

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &num) == 1
```

as you have said :

> The file is a simple line by line file with numbers in it, it has
>   10,000 elements in it.